# Spring integration http upload file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, multipart

I've written a code to upload images into my server. I've coded this with Spring integration, but when I try to resume multipartfile into service I get this errore

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.getInputStream(CommonsMultipartFile.java:123)
```

I've a controller which fill a model (file and description) and then send its, with message channel, to a service for processing image. This is a part of my integration-context

```
<channel id="photoProcessingChannel">
        <queue />
    </channel>
    <outbound-channel-adapter channel="photoProcessingChannel" method="processingBufferphoto" ref="BufferphotoService">
        <poller fixed-rate="2000"/>
    </outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't this sample help you https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/multipart-http ?

Comment: My case is different, I would to upload file, through controller, and send it to a service to save into DB

Comment: Well, I guess you should convert `MultipartFile` to `byte[]` in that `@Controller` and send to the `channel` just only them.